# Vue 3 date picker with browser build?

Tags: vue.js

Is there a Vue 3 datepicker with a browser build (i.e, which I can simply use from a CDN)? I have a Vue 2 application which doesn't use bundling, which has been using vuejs-datepicker. I'm now trying to upgrade to Vue 3, but vuejs-datepicker breaks under Vue 3. There is a Vue 3 replacement (https://icehaunter.github.io/vue3-datepicker/), but it doesn't have a browser build.

Answer (score 1):

Hi it might be a bit late but you can use

https://vue3datepicker.com/ in the browser.

Of course you dont have to import in your main js but you do need to include it as a component like this:

```
Datepicker: VueDatePicker,
```

then you will be able to use it like this:

```
<Datepicker id=""><Datepicker>
```

Comment: @jasie Sometimes new users try to enter xml as plaintext (instead of code format) which will not render properly. Often it's good to check for hidden XML in the markup of the answer.

Comment: Nice component, but strange that it allows for selection for year, month but not day. If the time select component can be hidden it would be perfect.

Answer (score -1):

```
<DatePicker v-model="date"  textinput :maxDate="new Date()" ref="date"
 id="@Html.IdFor(m => ""name="@Html.NameFor(m => m.Customer.DateOfBirth)"
  value="@(Model.Customer.DateOfBirth?.ToString("d"))"
  ></DatePicker>
```